# Django Form not saving uploaded image

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i have a little app that i am developing for study purposes using django framework. It has a Form that creates a object in the database and that object has a imagefield.

When i create this object using the form, all the data is saved successfully except the image. But, if i create a object using the same image in the admin page, it saves correctly...

This is my settings for the media in settings.py / urls.py

project settings.py media config:

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`
`MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'`

project urls.py media config:

`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

I have specified a path where the media should be uploaded in my models.py:

`cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='recipes/cover/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, default='')`

In my forms.py i have created a fileinput widget so the user could upload a file for the cover :

it's a model form btw.

```
cover = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.FileInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'span-2'
            }
        ),
    )
```

In my forms.html i have included the enctype as multipart/form-data:

```
<form class="main-form container"
        method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action="{{ form_action }}">
```

And, i have used the request.FILES when handling the form in the post function :

full post function :

```
def post(self, request, id=None):
        recipe = self.get_recipe(id)

        form = AuthorRecipeForm(
            data=request.POST or None,
            files=request.FILES or None,
            instance=recipe
        )

        if form.is_valid():
            # valid form to save
            recipe = form.save(commit=False)
            recipe.author = request.user
            recipe.preparation_steps_is_html = False
            recipe.is_published = False
            recipe.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Recipe Saved Successfully !')

            return redirect(
                reverse('authors:dashboard_recipe_edit', args=(recipe.pk,))
            )

        return self.render_recipe(form=form)
```

The object created with admin page uploads and saves the cover successfully at the path, like this:

[image: admin cover path]

The object created with form doesn't upload to the correct path and it leads to a 404 page :

[image: form created object cover path]

Image Example after creating one object with admin and other object with forms using the exactly same image :

[image: example]

Tried some things to solve this but mostly was related to the request.FILES and the enctype in the form ...

If anyone needs the full source code, it's on my github : https://github.com/bryanoliveira11/Curso-Django-Web

Thanks for any help in advance !

I've tried to validate request.FILES and enctype in the form. Expected a succefully upload for the image when using django forms.

Comment: Have you tried making `cover` a `FileField` (as opposed to a `CharField` it is now)?